# Position sticky to make table rows stick to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, sticky

Hello I am trying to make table with columns that will be able to stick to each other while I am scrolling horizontally. I am using position sticky and it works correctly with the first column, problem starts when the second or third columns are added. Especially that other columns are always different width which makes me unable to use same width multiplied by number of columns.

Can I make them sticky to each other without knowing what width will they be? And is there possibility to make text appear on top of other without them colliding with each other and making a unreadable mess?

```css
.sticky-col {
  position: sticky !important;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:2000px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="sticky-col">Firstname</th>
    <th class="sticky-to-left-elem">Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Jill</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e0xc69dg/

Comment: "Stick to each other" isn't a very specific behavior description. It looks more like you want collapse or overlap. Please revise to be more clear about that.

Answer (score 1):

You had a good start you can apply your style to all the `td` and `tr`

```css
td,
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:2000px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="sticky-col">Firstname</th>
    <th class="sticky-to-left-elem">Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Jill</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-col">Eve</td>
    <td class="sticky-to-left-elem">Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This solves the second problem, the first is still there, whole clue was so that i can have 1 column moving horizontaly then other adds to it so i move two collumns and if i want i can get 3 columns to move horizontaly next to each other, not on top of each other.

Comment: And is there solution without using background-color?

Comment: If you don't have `background-color` then your rows are `transparent` and allow to see the rows behind

Answer (score 0):

Change the left property of the second and third columns.
Try 100px in your example, then I will stick 100px from the left.

You also need to fiddle a little bit with some background color and maybe some text-align of the table headers.

Comment: You should create a demo using a snippet in the editor. Go ahead and copy down the snippet from the question and modify it.